# Parsing a section of a pipe-delimited string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a pipe-delimited string that ends with a `|`. I need the information between the second last `|` and the last `|`.

Example:

```
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|ijk|
```

I need to return `ijk`. The string will always have 9 pipes if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Call me insane, but this is what I came up with:

```
CREATE TABLE #SomeTable (
    id INT, 
    content VARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #SomeTable VALUES
    (1, 'a|b|c|d|e|f|Aloha|'),
    (2, 'a|b|c|d|e|f|From|'),
    (3, 'a|b|c|d|e|f|Hawaii|')

SELECT 
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LEFT(content, LEN(content)-1)), 0,CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(left(content, LEN(content)-1)),0)))
FROM #SomeTable
```

Explanation (from the inside out):

- Strip the last pipe (`|`)
- Reverse the whole string
- Find the next pipe (ex last)
- Extract the characters up until the next pipe.
- Reverse the string again.

Here's another take:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(content), 0, CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(content),2))),'|','')
FROM #SomeTable
```

- Reverse the string.
- Get the position of the next pipe (start looking from the second position to skip the first (ex last) pipe.
- Reverse the string.
- Replace the last pipe.

Comment: @JoeObbish please, feel free to edit, I would be more than flattered as I already tried and didn't worked... hahah